# How to get an arbitrary result set with Rails ActiveRecord that includes column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to do a complex SQL query that crosses several models and joins data; This is a sort of one-off adhoc report within my application, so I am not able to do this through standard model syntax.

I looked at `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows`, and this is very much what I want, but it returns a straight up array or arrays without including column names.  Ideally I would like something that works in the same manner as `select_rows`, but returns some more information, along the lines of an array of dictionaries so that I can use key value lookups when building out my report page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_all).

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use `results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)` and use `results.rows` to get the array of rows and `results.columns` to get the array of column names.

Comment: While it is possible to get the columns this way, it does not allow me the key value lookup I need.